# Getting XBee-API to compile and run under Netbeans

Tags: java, api, maven, netbeans, xbee

The question is howto install XBee-API in Netbeans for use with other projects?

The answer should be to simply download the maven project from github and import into Netbeans. Easy-peasy.  The reality is not so simple. As a Java noobie it has taken me a day to get Xbee API to compile and run under Netbeans.

XBee-API version 0.9.1 from Github is in a Maven project that imports directly into Netbeans but it won't compile without further work. For initial tests, I used the Digi SDK kit connected via a USB/serial cable to my win10 PC. I was running a XBee S2C Digimesh device.  Ultimately the reason I am using XBee_API is communicate with a Raspberry Pi 3B via I2C.

The first XBee-API class to try to run is "OpenCloseConnectionsTest" found in the Test folder.  This provides very detailed debug information that should help with troubleshooting.  If this will run, then everything else should as well.

First error was because the XBee-API POM file did not include a version tag.  My POM now looks like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.5</source>
<target>1.5</target>                                      
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Next I was missing RxTx files.  On my win10 installation I was missing the following files in the following locations:

```
...\Program Files\Java\jkd1.6.0_01\jre\bin\rxtxSerial.dll

...\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\jre\lib\ext\RXTXcomm.jar
```

I downloaded these from [here](http://jlog.org/rxtx-win.html). Once I placed these files in these locations, Netbeans found them without further action/config.  I still have a warning because these files aren't quite the same version.

Finally, I needed to edit the source code to set the comm port ID.  In my case, the XBee was on "COM5".

I could not find any single source that has all of the above information.  A lot of information I found was outdated and some was simply wrong.  Hopefully this write-up will help others.

Comment: This looks very helpful. Unfortunately, we need answers to have an on-topic question here. Would you be able to tweak this so that the original problem is presented, such that it can be answered by some of this material in an answer below?

Comment: OK, this was an answer looking for a question but I have tweaked it. Since writing this up, I have found that the github version 0.9.1 is not the latest.  The latest version 0.9.2 is on Maven Central Repository.  The difference is important for me because 0.9.2 includes a socket function that allows multiplexed comms over a single channel.  Until ver 0.9.2, that code was separate from XBee-API.  So now I have to figure out how to import and create a new project from Maven Central.

Comment: It is still not in our required Q&A format, unfortunately. Answers go down below, and are quite distinct from questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as useful as it is, it is an answer without a separate question.

Comment: Really!!!!  This is an information exchange forum which just happens to promote a question and answer format.  Don't let format take precedent over content.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, we're quite strict on it. It should still be possible to make a Q&A out of this, but I appreciate that takes more effort than you bargained for. I don't want to put you off contributing, but this format is pretty much key to the whole site. (It's also not a forum, and thus very different to the discussion sites you may have used before).

Comment: You said you spent a full day trying to get this working. You could improve your question by laying out some of the specific problems (Errors would be great!) that you ran into and then phrasing your answer as a way of dealing with them.

Comment: `This is an information exchange forum which just happens to promote a question and answer format` → **No**. This is a Questions & Answers site. Why it is so is not up for debate on the site itself, you may want to hit [meta] once you have sufficient reputation. This is not a tutorial or a blogging site. For future readers to be efficiently able to relate to your issue, we need you to **ask a specific question** (for example "How to compile XBee-API for Netbeans") and provide data as pointed out by jpmc26. Then even other users could be able to answer your question, maybe better than you did.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I am working on an answer to my question.  So in order to get the very latest version 0.9.2 of XBee-API, I need to install a project from the Maven Central Repository into Netbeans.  I found a couple of posts that pointed me [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Create_new_project).
I didn't find this useful at all.  The answer might be there somewhere but it assumes a level of understanding of Maven and Ant that I don't have, so I experimented.  I created a new Maven project in Netbeans and then copied the content of the XBee-API POM file I found in Maven Central and pasted that to replace the content of the default POM file in the new Maven project I had created.

My understanding is that Maven will download all the files needed based on the POM file, but it didn't.  Most of the files were downloaded, but not all.  I got the following warnings:

```
    Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.rapplogic:xbee-api:jar:0.9.2
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin is missing. @ line 60, column 21
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 51, column 21
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing. @ line 86, column 21
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing. @ line 99, column 21
```

And also:

```
Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.1:revision (get-the-git-infos) on project xbee-api: The plugin pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.1 requires Maven version [3.1.1,) -> [Help 1]
```

This might make sense to anyone that knows something about Maven, but that's not me.  It looks like I need to upgrade Maven which is only a couple of months old since that is how long I have been using Java for.

I found that I am already running the latest Maven ver 3.5.0.  The error message says I need 3.1.1 so upgrading Maven isn't possible and downgrading back to 3.1.1 seems like a bad idea.  Time to change tack and look at using a later version of the plugin.

I found others who have had this problem [here](https://github.com/oreillymedia/restful_java_jax-rs_2_0/issues/2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456990/warning-build-plugins-plugin-version-for-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-deploy) but no solutions.  I found this response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299963/how-can-i-define-plugin-versions-correctly-in-maven-pom-xml) that indicates the problem is that there is no version specified for each plugin in the POM.  So it seems like Apache has changed the rules (requiring a version to be specified in the POM) but haven't provided a tool to update POMs. This seems to be something that could be scanned for and corrected within Maven Central. The POM I am running is only 5 months old and yet it won't build without manual intervention.

To fix the version problem, I had to search Maven Central for each plugin to get the latest/right version number and amend the POM.  How bad is that!!  That process cleared all but one fatal error.  I have now hit an impasse described in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903500/how-to-fix-pluginincompatibleexception)

The solution I am going to pursue is to work with the older version of XBee-API from Github.  This gives me the source code and it builds without issue.  I plan to modify this code to use I2C rather than RS232.  There is also beta code for a socket server.

Comment: Since writing the above, the developer has uploaded the latest version to Github.  I have downloaded this and been able to compile it.  I can see the benefits of Maven but I haven't been able to compile with it under Netbeans.