# How to fix PluginincompatibleException?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, compiler-errors, version

I am trying to build a project in Netbeans from Maven Central. When I first tried to build the project there were a number of error messages because plugins didn't have versions specified in the POM.  I fixed those problems.

I am running the latest version of Maven 3.5.0.  I specified in the POM the latest version of the plugin.  Here is the related section of the POM complete with the version number I added.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>validate-the-git-infos</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>

        <configuration>
            <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
            <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            <excludeProperties>
                <excludeProperty>git.build.*</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.commit.user.email</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.commit.message.*</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.commit.id.describe</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.commit.user.name</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.remote.origin.url</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.commit.id.abbrev</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.closest.tag.name</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.closest.tag.commit.count</excludeProperty>
                <excludeProperty>git.remote.origin.url</excludeProperty>
            </excludeProperties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I now get the follow fatal error:

```
cd D:\darren\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\XBee-API; "JAVA_HOME=D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121" cmd /c "\"\"D:\\Program Files\\Java\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\Program Files\\Java\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 install\""
Scanning for projects...
Inspecting build with total of 1 modules...
Installing Nexus Staging features:
  ... total of 1 executions of maven-deploy-plugin replaced with nexus-staging-maven-plugin

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building com.rapplogic:xbee-api 0.9.2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/pl/project13/maven/git-commit-id-plugin/2.2.2/git-commit-id-plugin-2.2.2.pom
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/pl/project13/maven/git-commit-id-plugin/2.2.2/git-commit-id-plugin-2.2.2.pom (13 KB at 25.6 KB/sec)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.729s
Finished at: Tue Jul 04 22:15:49 NZST 2017
Final Memory: 14M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.2:revision (get-the-git-infos) on project xbee-api: The plugin pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.2.2 requires Maven version [3.1.1,) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException
```

The [Wiki help page](https://cwiki.apache.org//confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginIncompatibleException) is no help.  There is no obvious way to resolve this problem and clear the error.

Comment: You can either update your build environment to the required Maven version or try using an older version of the plugin which still supports your Maven version.

Comment: I am already using the latest available versions of Maven and the plugin.  Going from Maven 3.5.0 back to 3.1.1.  It doesn't make sense for the latest version of the plugin to require a much earlier version of Maven.  If I did downgrade Maven, I am likely to hit problems with other plugins requiring a later version of Maven.